Chromedriver timeout issue with cookies in Python
I get the following exception when using Chromedriver from the following lines of code:
self.click(By.XPATH, searchtab_xpath)
self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, value)))

The following is the stacktrace:
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001028c6a80 chromedriver + 4385408
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001028bf38c chromedriver + 4354956
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001024dcb0c chromedriver + 281356
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010251f2f8 chromedriver + 553720
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000102557d24 chromedriver + 785700
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000102513eec chromedriver + 507628
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001025148c4 chromedriver + 510148
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010288e43c chromedriver + 4154428
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000102892ea0 chromedriver + 4173472
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000102873ff8 chromedriver + 4046840
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010289378c chromedriver + 4175756
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000102866fb8 chromedriver + 3993528
12  chromedriver                        0x00000001028b121c chromedriver + 4297244
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001028b1398 chromedriver + 4297624
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001028bef84 chromedriver + 4353924
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001823d2f94 _pthread_start + 136
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001823cdd34 thread_start + 8

Chrome version is 126.0.6478.127 (arm64) and chromedriver_version is 126.0.6478.126, using selenium 4.11.2.
